# Laravel check if user is deactivated before mail is send

Tags: laravel, laravel-7, laravel-authentication

I'm using Laravel Version 7, and in my users' table, I have an additional field called "deactivated" to deactivate a user. However, I don't want a deactivated user to be able to send himself a Password Reset E-Mail via the built-in function. So, how can I check if the user is deactivated before a Password Reset E-Mail is sent?

Comment: if account deactived then which value contains the `deactivated` field?

Comment: See the sendPasswordResetNotification method of your user model.  Check for deactivated there, and through a custom error you can handle accordingly.

Comment: Thanks Kurt , that worked